# Which method to use for anomaly detection?

Tags: data-mining, computational-statistics

I think people here could guide me in solving a problem related to anomaly detection in Computer Science. The term *anomaly* here refers to some undesired event occuring in the system like a virus infection.

I could get to know about it from more than one source. For example, after having extracted a value from two different data structures, if there is a difference it is certain that virus infection is there.

In order to remove the false positive cases, information is gathered from different data structures or mechanisms. Hence, certain information are less trusted and certain information are more trusted.

I am looking for a mathematical method, that could easily handle this type of situations. Whether Fuzzy/Genetic Algorithm/Neural Net fits here? Found in some places they are using normality-based approach (using z-score). Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: [Anomaly Detection : A Survey (2009)](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/papers/anomaly-survey.php)